# how can I add a domain to a related field in openerp?

Tags: dns, filtering

how can i add a domain to a relational field so it'll only show a list of products whose values are > 0 in openerp. Sorry am still learning programming with openerp. Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

In your current object from which you are creating relationship with product.product, say for ex, its many2one relation, so in that case,

```
'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', domain=[('VALUE','>',0)])
```

VALUE means the product field on which, you want to add condition. By doing this, when you will click on that product field, it will list out only those products who are matching with your domain.